# JavaFX: Heavy laggs after a specific time

Tags: java, performance, user-interface, javafx, lag

We're working on a little game with JavaFX for the GUI. The game is turn-based and after each turn we update our borderPane (.setCenter()) with the new board (this is an array which representes the tiles in the game). The tiles are drawn as JavaFX-Canvas objects.

We have the problem that every time after 155-160 turns the whole application begins to lag. CPU usage is increasing to 80% on my computer by one turn (e.g. turn 154: 1 % und turn 155: 80%). We also got an outOfMemoryError but not every time.

Additionally, we implemented some sysos for debugging and all the methods on our board array with the game logics are correctly and fastly iterated. The lag must be something in the JavaFX-Thread.

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I commented the update-Method for the gui out, and the game works without the gui refreshes. Therefore I think it should be a problem with JavaFx Thread

Comment: Sounds like a memory problem, the old boards semm not to be garbage-collected and sum up in Heap... if Java get near max heap, the garbage collector will use up all the CPU.... perhaps your old boards are still referenced somehow (timeline or listener registrations...)... is it possible to post the source?...

Comment: Hey (:
Of course, here you are: http://pastebin.com/ZzAwLya4

Thanks alot :)

The 'updateSpielfeld()'-method runs the update. If I comment 'tabelle = erzeugeSpielfeld(neuesSpielfeld.getTiles());' or
                'inhalt.setCenter(tabelle);' out, the game works fast (but with no gui update). So here could be the problem.

Comment: Read up on some of the [related JavaFX issue tracker requests](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22canvas%20clear%22) and see if they address your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gc maybe isnt cleaning old objects. Did you try to use the daneobjects but not creating a new one every time?

Greets